# How do I implement a branching logic in Reactor that performs a conditional database logic?

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-webflux, reactor

The logic im trying to perform

```
    1. fetch db item 1
    2. fetch db item 2
    3. flag db item 1 as SUCCESS if db item 2 is found

Alternative Path:
    3.B. flag db item 1 as FAILURE if db item 2 was not found
    4.B. throw an exception upstream
```

Heres my code:

//MyService.java

```
Datastore datastore;

public Mono<Void> doTheThing(Long someId) {
   Mono<Item1> item1 = datastore
     .findItem1(someId)
     .cache();

   return item1
     .flatMap(it -> datastore.findItem2(it.getItem2Id())
     .then(item1.map(it -> it.withStatus("SUCCESS").flatMap(datastore::save))
      
      //HOW do i catch the error and persist item1 with "FAILED" status?
      //.doOnError(NoItem2Exception.class, item1.map(it -> it.withStatus("FAILURE").flatMap(datastore::save)) 
      // ^--- i have no clue what to do here
    
      .onErrorMap(NoItem1Exception.class, (e) -> new BusinessException(e))   

     .then();
}
```

Its dependency:

//Datastore.java

```
class Datastore {

   Mono<Item1> findItem1(Long item1Id) {
     return Mono.just(new Item1()); //not important
   }

   Mono<Item1> save(Item1 item1) { //not impt, just saves the item }

   Mono<Item2> findItem2(Long item2Id) {
      return db2.findById(item2Id)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NoItem2Exception());
   }
  
}
```

In the Service code, how do i branch out the logic when an exception is thrown (`NoItem2Exception`) from the `findItem2` method?

My first step would be to flag the Item1 from the first DB query, then after that I want to bubble up the exception by wrapping it with another exception (not important, I know how to capture exceptions from the controller)

Answer (score 1):

[`Mono.onErrorResume`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-) seems to be the method you are looking for. It allows you to switch to a different Mono (in your case `database.save(Item1)`) if a certain exception is encountered:

```java
public Mono<Void> doTheThing(Long someId) {
    Mono<Item1> item1 = datastore
            .findItem1(someId);

    return item1
            .flatMap(it -> datastore.findItem2(it.getItem2Id())
                    .then(it.withStatus("SUCCESS").flatMap(datastore::save))
                    .onErrorResume(NoItem2Exception.class, e -> it.withStatus("FAILURE")
                            .flatMap(datastore::save)
                            .then(Mono.error(new BusinessException(e)))));
}
```